# How to write an EXE which is also a COM Server in Delphi

Tags: delphi, com, activex-exe

I have a Delphi (2007) application which is just a standard exe, and I would like to add a COM interface to it. I already have a COM dll which exports several COM objects and this is working perfectly. However when I attempted to insert the COM logic from the dll (ie the "exports" and "{$R *.TLB}" and the relevant uses) into the EXE's dpr file it all compiles perfectly but refuses to register when I call regsvr32 myname.exe

I also tried creating an completely new VCLForms application and adding a AutomationObject to it via the IDE wizards but Delphi does not seem to want me to do that as no activex components are available.

Is it even possible to do what I attempting? If so, does anyone have any idea on what might be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running on 64 bit Windows?  Vista/7?

Comment: Yes, I am running Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Seems like you got your answer. My point was that on 64 bit Windows you have to work a little bit to get the 32 bit version of regsvr32. Of course I didn't twig that since this is an exe rather than a dll you don't need a separate program to host the code to do self-reg.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure regsvr32 works, you need to run the app.exe /regserver or app.exe /unregserver.

Comment: Indeed, just run your application with /regserver or /unregserver. This is all handled in the ComServ.pas unit.

Answer (score 1):

Is your exe exporting [DllRegisterServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682162%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [DllUnregisterServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691457%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes it does. I just noticed that regsvr32 does not show the successful registration dialog. In fact, it just shows an hourglass for a few seconds and then exits.

Comment: what is the return value DllRegisterServer then?

Comment: I don't know, but as Richard Chamberlain pointed out the error of my ways I'm not going to try and find out. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I think he will return soon, then :)